# Where is the shader panel in Blender?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

Here is the part of the [tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Landscape_Modeling_I:_Basic_Terrain) that I'm following that I'm stuck on:

> With your landscape selected, go to the Shading Panel (F5) and add a new material.
>   Under the Shaders tab, drop the Specular value to 0.

It can't be the "shading" panel in the properties window, because I don't see a "specular value". None of the function keys work for me. I'm using Blender 2.77.

Comment: Welcome. That tutorial is for Blender's version 2.44 which is quite old as of now, especially after noticeable UI change with version 2.5, hence you see so many differences (note the "applicable for version number" in the top of the page for every lesson there). It's better to use lessons for  newer versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are

[image]

Possibilies:
- Make sure you are in Blender internal
- Shading panel may be collapsed, or dragged below.